# How to get Bootstrap timepicker date object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, timepicker

Currently using bootstrap timepicker with Angularjs

http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker

The control is displaying well but when i set the ng-model and get the startTime

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" ng-disabled="!useTime" data-template="dropdown" data-show-seconds="true" data-default-time="11:25 AM" data-show-meridian="true" data-minute-step="5" ng-model="startTime" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

The startTime assigned is a string like "11:25 AM" instead of a date object i can manipulate in javascript.

How can i get date object? Do i need to convert it manually?

Comment: Hmm.. no one has done this before?

Comment: I still haven't found the right answer. For now, I have to handle this manually by using mement.js library for date conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Think this answer seems to be similar to your question.Hope it provides some insight.
[Time Binding issue in Bootstrap timepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018159/angular-bootstrap-time-picker-not-binding-time)

Comment: My issues is the bootstrap timepicker returns me as a string and i need to convert it manually. When i change the input value, the ngmodel value i got back is a string

Comment: So you need to convert your string time to some universal time?

Comment: Preferably as a date object i can manipulate for whatever reason.

Comment: so I don't know how you are solving this issues?

Comment: I'm getting date object with time.From there i'm splitting time and date

Comment: I mean are you getting the date object when user select a new time? Can you show me a bit of code in plucker or similar

Comment: Sorry @in.visible.I'm poor in handling plunker.But you can check the documentation of angular bootstrap timepicker.And the link iin the answer for further reference

Comment: So i want to know is that, you are able to get new date object when user picks a new time? using the ng-model

Comment: on a closer look, it looks like we are using two different bootstrap timepicker