# Angular Bootstrap Time Picker not Binding time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm not able to bind time which I'm setting in the controller like this

```
 $scope.info.startTime="12:10:03";
```

This is my time picker control in HTML

```
<span class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"  tabindex="5"
                 ng-model="info.startTime" placeholder="hh:mm"
                 is-open="datepickerOpened1"
                 close-text="Close"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" ng-click="openStartTime($event, 'time')">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
            </button>
                <div dropdown is-open="timepickerOpened1">
              <span class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <timepicker ng-model="info.startTime"  show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
              </span>
            </div>
          </span>
        </span>
```

Reference:[Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set date object in ng-model instead of string.

Change

```
$scope.info.startTime="12:10:03";
```

To

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(12);
d.setMinutes(10);
$scope.info.startTime=d;
```

Comment: Hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds can be set in one go:  `d.setHours(12, 10, 0, 0)`. ;-)

Comment: What if the time picker is inside ng repeat.Will there be any change in the bindings?

Comment: No there should not be any change. You just need to set date object.